# CATransform3DGetAffineTransform for flipping a view not working when called one after another

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-animation, catransform3d

I am developing an aquarium app. I need to generate motions of fishes in it. Fish should swim and when reaching to one end of its aquarium should take a turn(or flip) and move to other end, again a turn(or flip) and back to its original position.

fish forword motion is working fine with it also take turn(flip) on reaching to its end. but when it reaches its other end the flip animation plus further animation skips suddenly.

following are the codes i am using.....

```
CGFloat originalChildXpos = fishView.frame.origin.y;

/************************************** Animation 1 **************************************************************/

[UIView animateWithDuration:15.0
                      delay:1.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{                         
                     fishView.frame =CGRectMake(0, fishView.frame.origin.y, fishView.frame.size.width, fishView.frame.size.height);                         
                 }completion:NULL];


/*********************************** Animation 2 ****************************************************************/
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.4
                      delay:3.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     fishView.transform = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

                 }completion:NULL];



/********************************* Animation 3 ****************************************************************/
[UIView animateWithDuration:10
                      delay:3.4
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     fishView.frame = CGRectMake(-aquariumView.frame.size.width, fishView.frame.origin.y, fishView.frame.size.width, fishView.frame.size.height);
                 }completion:NULL];



/*************************************** Animation 4 *****************************************************/
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.4
                      delay:13.4
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     fishView.transform = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

                 }completion:NULL];


/************************************* Animation 5 *******************************************/
[UIView animateWithDuration:13.8
                      delay:2.2
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     fishView.frame = CGRectMake(originalChildXpos, fishView.frame.origin.y, fishView.frame.size.width, fishView.frame.size.height);
                 }completion:NULL];
```

i think i miss something while using `CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(CATransform3DMakeRotation())` function, for the second time flip rotation.....

can anyone over here show me way out of it and explain where i am going wrong

i would also like to know while using `CATransform3D` for rotation, do coordinate axes with respect to view, on which the transform is applied changes or get effected??

Comment: Is `fishView` a view? You are using it like a layer. Also, frame and transform don't play nice together. You shouldn't use them like that (the documentation even says so)

Comment: yes, fishview is of view class.

Comment: but flip animation using CATransform3DMakeRotation is working fine for first time but not second time. why so??

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it's because a -π and a π rotation is the same transform.

Comment: checked by replacing -pi by pi....but same result...

Comment: Of course, at step 1 you have π and at step 3 you change it to -π

Comment: can we apply same transform by CATransform3D on same uiview one after another??

Answer (score 0):

```
  CGFloat originalChildXpos = fishView.frame.origin.y;
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform=fishView.transform; // step one add this

    /************************************** Animation 1 **************************************************************/

    [UIView animateWithDuration:15.0
                          delay:1.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{                         
                         fishView.frame =CGRectMake(0, fishView.frame.origin.y, fishView.frame.size.width, fishView.frame.size.height);                         
                     }completion:NULL];


    /*********************************** Animation 2 ****************************************************************/
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.4
                          delay:3.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         fishView.transform = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

                     }completion:NULL];



    /********************************* Animation 3 ****************************************************************/
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10
                          delay:3.4
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         fishView.frame = CGRectMake(-aquariumView.frame.size.width, fishView.frame.origin.y, fishView.frame.size.width, fishView.frame.size.height);
                     }completion:NULL];



    /*************************************** Animation 4 *****************************************************/
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.4
                          delay:13.4
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         fishView.transform = currentTransform;  // step 2 replace here 

                     }completion:NULL];


    /************************************* Animation 5 *******************************************/
    [UIView animateWithDuration:13.8
                          delay:2.2
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         fishView.frame = CGRectMake(originalChildXpos, fishView.frame.origin.y, fishView.frame.size.width, fishView.frame.size.height);
                     }completion:NULL];
```

For transform u did x = y in initial so now your x became y 
and in the next statement you changed y =y so no effect...

Comment: still the same result....fish still responding to 1 rotation/flip function, not for other...

may i have a good tutorial link for such transformations...

Comment: i got u...during transformation for rotation coordinate axes get transform too..but i need to study more regarding this...can you please provide me a good tutorial link that can help me further....

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial  http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes  http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/core-animation   i followed this